# How is the spread devided between buyer, seller and market maker?

Tags: trading, stock-exchanges

For a given stock, if:

- a seller places a sell limit order at 100 dollars;
- a buyer places a buy limit order at 200 dollars;

At what price will the transaction be executed and who will pay/get how much?

Comment: @DStanley can you elaborate a bit. What do you mean by "move"? Shouldn't the market maker detect automatically, that someone is willing to buy at a price higher than what the seller wants and fulfill the orders automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At what price will the transaction be executed and who will pay/get how much?

There will be two transactions. The market maker will buy the stock from the seller for $100 and sell it to the buyer for $200.

Comment: +1, interesting, i did not realize the market makers role and their potential for profit like this.

Comment: Obviously in reality the profit per transaction is much, much smaller, but they make up for it in volume :)

Comment: Some brokers permit you to set a limit on orders that prevents one from buying "X" pct above or selling "X" pct below current price.  It prevents one from from being screwed on a fill (buy at $200 when the stock is $100) since the order is flagged and rejected.

Comment: Wait - why wouldn't the orders just cross without market maker intervention, at the price of whoever has time priority?